# Celery Daemon issue

Tags: celery

> /root/myproject/ ├── requirements.txt └── src
> ├── client.py
> ├── config.yml
> ├── dhcp.py
> ├── logs
> │   └── server.log
> ├── privatekey
> ├── publickey
> ├── server.py
> ├── settings.py
> ├── sh_wg.py
> └── tasks.py

Tasks.py

```
app = Celery('wg', broker='redis://localhost:6379/1')
app.conf.result_backend = 'redis://localhost:6379/2'
app.conf.update(
    task_serializer='json',
    result_serializer='json',
    timezone='Europe/Dublin',
    enable_utc=True,
)
@app.tasks
def add():
  code here
```

when I run :

> celery -A tasks worker -l INFO

- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         wg:0x7f2f2674cc18
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/1
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://localhost:6379/2
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 1 (prefork)
  -- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
  --- ***** -----
  -------------- [queues]
  .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
  Everything is working fine.

now i am trying to run this as a daemon

> celery --app tasks multi start worker --pidfile=/var/log/celery/%n.pid
> --logfile=/var/log/celery/%n%I.log --loglevel=INFO

**in the log file.**

> [2020-10-15 06:56:37,820: ERROR/MainProcess]
> consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno
> 111] Connection refused. Trying again in 2.00 seconds... (1/100)
>
> [2020-10-15 06:56:39,833: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect
> to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
> Trying again in 4.00 seconds... (2/100)
>
> [2020-10-15 06:56:43,849: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect
> to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111] Connection refused.
> Trying again in 6.00 seconds... (3/100)

it did not pick the right broker. i am not too sure what i am doing wrong.

Comment: Which version of Celery are you having this issue with?

Comment: celery --version
4.4.7 (cliffs)